# Pygame, Keeping sprite in a border, clamp_ip() won't work properly

Tags: python, pygame

Code:

```
def main():
    running = True

    while running:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

        player.update()
        enemy.update(player)
        #player.rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)

        screen.fill(BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)
        screen.blit(enemy.image, enemy.rect)

        pygame.display.update()




class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, position):
        super(Mob, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('red'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=position)
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(position)
        self.speed = 3

    def hunt_player(self, player):
        player_position = player.rect.center
        direction = player_position - self.position
        velocity = direction.normalize() * self.speed

        self.position += velocity
        self.rect.center = self.position

    def update(self, player):
        self.hunt_player(player)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, position):
        super(Player, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('blue'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=position)

        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(position)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = 6

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.velocity.x = -self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.velocity.x = self.speed
        else:
            self.velocity.x = 0

        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            self.velocity.y = -self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
            self.velocity.y = self.speed
        else:
            self.velocity.y = 0

        self.position += self.velocity
        self.rect.center = self.position


player = Player(position=(350, 220))
enemy = Mob(position=(680, 400))

startscreen()
main()
```

Here is a 'Chase' style game which I've been dabbling over the past few months.
Could anyone help me with creating a border for my sprite? I've managed to use the clamp_ip() method but it only stops the image from leaving the screen and not the actual sprite so I've took it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Too much code, please provide a [Complete, Minimal, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual position of the `player` sprite is stored in the `self.position` attribute, but calling `player.rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)` only affects the `self.rect` attribute and the `position` will still be changed each frame.

I'd check if the player is outside of the screen area with the `pygame.Rect.contains` method, if yes, call `clamp_ip` and set the `player.position` to the new `player.rect.center`.

```
if not border_rect.contains(player.rect):
    player.rect.clamp_ip(border_rect)
    player.position = pygame.math.Vector2(player.rect.center)
```

Comment: Thank you good sir this works with a little bit of tampering! By any chance could you help me with my collision function? When two rects collide the game display changes to a game over function but then when I need the first start screen function to come back it wont as the  if player.rect.colliderect(enemy): has already recorded a collision. I've tried to play around with some if not statements but i can't get anywhere. Appreciate it!

Comment: I've upvoted but it wont show as i'm currently still in the first 15 days of my account being created. Will do pal, respect.